# In a particular app in android-it says Unfortunately app has been stopped

Tags: java, android

I am running a example of fragment,while running on emulator ,it says Unfortunately app has been stopped

```
09-30 14:15:19.518: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
09-30 14:15:19.528: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aust.myfragments/com.aust.myfragments.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.aust.myfragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. 09-30 14:15:19.538: E/AndroidRuntime(336): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
```

You may be trying to apply the theme on `ActionBarActivity`. Either use AppCompat theme or change your `ActionbarActivity` to `Activity`

Refer [this discussion](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/you-need-to-use-a-themeappcompat-theme-or-descendent-crystal-ball-crashes) and [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/error-you-need-to-use-a-themeappcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity) for more information.